# Software helping people with depression

Tags: health

I am looking for software that can help people who have depression.

It can be for any platform (web, desktop, mobile).

It can present a todo list (ex: [Superbetter](https://www.superbetter.com/)), help people understand depression better (ex: [Depression Quest](http://www.depressionquest.com/)), give suggestions for what can be done given different circumstances (ex: [You feel like shit](http://philome.la/jace_harr/you-feel-like-shit-an-interactive-self-care-guide/play)), or help people with depression in another way.

With kind regards.

Comment: I think people with depression should have more real-world contact to humans and less contact to computers. I guess software does not help. I like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonviolent_Communication